# jquery selecting and copying tr

Tags: jquery

I wish to duplicate a tr tag in jquery. I have the following. The issue with this code is that
`$(rowId)`  doesn't include the "tr"  but just the contents inside it. So the first tag is a `<td>` not a `<tr>`. How can select this element also.

```
      $('.addLine').click(function () {
          var rowId = $(this).attr('rel');
          var rowId = "#" + rowId;
          var newRow = $(rowId);
          var htmlStr = $(newRow).html(); 
          $(newRow).append(htmlStr);

      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.html()` returns the inside of the element selected, you can use `.clone()` to make a copy of the entire element, which you can append.

```
 $('.addLine').click(function () {
      var rowId = $(this).attr('rel');
      var newRow = $("#"+rowId).clone().appendTo("youTableOrSomething");
  });
```

Comment: thanks, nearly there. How would i append after the current tr. ie the above puts the tr at the end of the table but i would like to put it under your current selection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$('.addLine').click(function () {
          var rowId = $(this).attr('rel');
          var rowId = "#" + rowId;
          var newRow = $(rowId).parent();
          var htmlStr = $(newRow).html(); 
          $(newRow).append(htmlStr);

});
```

Comment: Won't this select the parent of the row (being the `<TBODY>` most likely) and duplicate all the contents of that `<TBODY>` ?